# Port-forwarding in router ZTE ZXHN F660: hidden settings

Tags: router, wireless-router, port-forwarding, default-settings

In my company, we have a ZTE ZXHN F660 router, and we need to do a port-forwarding to access a DB allocated in one of our machines through public IP.

We have login into router admin page (visit public ip and login with our user and pass), but our telecom provider seem to be hidden the port-forwarding settings. We just find a few info and settings such as change network name and pass, or disconnect the devices connected to the network.

Is it possible to access the port forwarding of the router another way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should login using administrator login/password (if you are able to get it somewhere, by default is "admin"/"admin") and then that option will be visible (alongside with many others, secured for admins only).

Comment: Tim I said I have logged in before, but being logged, the option is still hidden.

Comment: I believe that this router is provided by the telecom provider. If you are sure that Telecom provider has restricted port forwarding, then you can talk with them and get its access to proceed. Other way, if you have spare router you can try port forwarding with same. But you need to configure the settings from Telecom provider in spare router.

Answer (score -2):

You **CAN'T** do Port-Forwarding because your Router have **NOT** the feature as [Datasheet shows](http://enterprise.zte.com.cn/en/products/network_lnfrastructure/broadband_access/xpon_olt/201401/t20140109_416587.html).

No matter how many effort you do trying to find "*Administrator Passwords*" there is not a way to do because the Firmware lacks of this feature.

**Router Features**

- IPv6 / IPv4 Dual Stack
- NAT/ SNTP
- ALG
- Static routing, and dynamic routing in RIPV1/V2
- PPPoE Client/Pass Through
- DNS Client/Server
- IGMP v1/ v2/ v3
- IGMP proxy/snooping