# ZTE F660 Router admin panel on public IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

we have f660 router from ZTE. Router have problem with soft that if you use some hack code you could get all config etc.

Problem with it is only that router have open 80 port for admin panel on our public IP. We want to block it or forward ports to one of lan machines.

We check all settings and can't find out solution to achieve that.

ZTE don't give any new firmware to fix this so we can't do nothing with update.

Can we please any hints? :)

Comment: Relevant: [Port-forwarding in router ZTE ZXHN F660: hidden settings](http://superuser.com/q/793445)

Comment: @DavidPostill i think it's not. "do a port-forwarding to access a DB allocated in one of our machines" They don't want to protect router from begin hacked by public panel. We have full access to admin and we don't find any way to forward port 80 from use by admin panel.

Comment: Hmm. Do you read Indonesian? http://belajarotodidak.blogspot.com/2014/03/port-forwarding-di-zte-f660.html (google translate seem to work reasonably well).

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-udnlRcfFO5Y/UykUMHOmoFI/AAAAAAAAAno/2IlIC4J3m34/s1600/application+list.png Application panel not admin panel. Try forwarding port 80 from here.